# strange behaviour of ajax under chrome

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, jquery

Hello I have very odd problem. this never happened to me before.

I have an ajax request invoked by onclick. Everywhere it works normal but not under the chromest Onclick is set to button.

Now the target of the ajax is an url that can be accessed only via POST request.

This is the info now the problem

When I enter the page and I click o  the button the request is not invoked. It goes to error block with message "error". Always happens like that. No request jus error. I have no js error in console.
Now when i change request type from post to get and reload page and try it again i get error on request cause get request can not get to the url. This is correct. There is requezt and i get response as expected. When i switch back to post from get and do e erything from start if works. I do not know why. The request is invoked and it gets proper response. But when i reload the page i am geting to starting point. The request sin not invoking just geting to error block. I need to switch to get, make a bad invoke and switch back to post to start the request. But when i refresh again can not do nothing.

What is going on. This can not be a code problem cause it is working even u der ie8

A other ajaxes are working properly

```
function poll() {
$.ajax({ 
    type: "POST",
    url: "/ajax/" + sendTo + "/" + mFrom,
    success: function(data){
        var messages = '';
        if(data != 'done') {
            console.log(data);
            for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                console.log(data[i]);
                if(data[i] !== undefined) {
                    messages += '<li>From ' + data[i].userFrom + ': ' + data[i].message + '</li>';
                }
            }
            console.log(messages);
            if(messages != '' && messages !== undefined) {
                $('#messagesList').prepend(messages);
            }
        }
    },
    complete: poll
});
}
```

// edit

I'm testing the code but this just doesn not want to work. Even a simple ajax query. Can chrome block something like this ?

Comment: Code please? Long paragraphs are not as meaningful specially when they are describing a long workflow

Comment: @JuanMendes i thought code isn't the problem here but i've added. my tests shown that it could be a empty ajax request (no config, no nothing) and it also didn't want to be invoked